# How to delete a field in Firestore document checking condition with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working with Flutter and Firebase. I have the following document:
[image]

I'd like to build a function that checks this specific document and delete all the Map (e.g. test1) where the field shouldDelete contains the number 1. How could I implement this function?

```dart
void check(
  String documentId,
) {
 final DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> mydoc = 
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection').doc(documentId);
}
```

Comment: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection').doc(documentId).delete(); thus this the one you looking for?

Comment: no Sorry, i'm looking for a way to implement the function that check the condition given and then I'll use .doc().delete()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the solution:

```dart
void convalida(
    String documentId,
    ) {
  final DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> mydoc= 
   FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection').doc(documentId);
  mydoc.get().then((value) =>
      value.data()!.forEach((key, value) {
        if(value["shouldDelete"]==1 ) {mydoc.update({key:FieldValue.delete()});}
      }
      )
  );

}
```

In this way we are not deleting only `shouldDelete` field but al the `test1` Map.
Hope this could help someone in the future.